# AppleScript: is it possible to limit string lengths that can be input in Safari text fields?

Tags: javascript, macos, safari, safari-extension, parental-control

I’m looking for an AppleScript that **limits the length of a number string that users can enter into a Safari (or any HTML pop-up) text field**. I’m not a scripter but could probably write a simple ‘tell application “Safari”’ if I knew the commands.

My 89-year old father-in-law is in the early stages of dementia. Every time he sees malware or pop-up scareware (think MacKeeper or SafeSearch search hijacker) on his Mac, or he receives a scam email, he whips out the credit card and pays whatever they are asking, and promptly forgets why he did it. Parental controls isn’t useful because isn’t buying anything from Apple and he still needs Internet access. However, he’s getting scammed left and right to the tune of hundreds and hundreds of dollars and I'm constantly removing malware (I do have admin access to his computer.)

I’d like him to continue to enjoy the Internet but make it impossible for him to enter credit card, bank account, or telephone numbers. Does anyone know if AppleScript supports this. If there is an easier solution than a script I'd be interested in hearing it.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using AppleScript I'd build a safari extension.
I don't think this is possible with AppleScript.
If you need help building the extension, feel free to drop me an email via my website: www.erikvanderplas.com.

Comment: Thanks, Eric. I've never built a Safari extension so this should be interesting. I'll hack at it for few days; expect that I'll probably need your help. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I went the JavaScript extension route. It's ugly because it's my first JavaScript. However, it pops-up the warning banner once on the first keypress of each web page and accomplishes the task.

```
function watchOut() {
    alert("DON'T USE THAT CREDIT CARD!");
    }

document.onkeypress = function() {
  document.onkeypress = null;
    watchOut();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use System Preferences. Head over to the Keyboard palette and click on the Text tab. Inside you’ll be able to create basic expandable snippets. It’s text expansion at its most rudimentary. Set it to replace his credit card, bank account, or telephone numbers with some other text like "Don't use that" each time.